# How can I find out what these files or processes do (linux)

Tags: linux, command-line, process

When I go onto a *nix system and look as `ps -A` or `-e` or `top` I get a large number of processes that are running. For example.

```
init
migration/0
ksoftirqd/0
events/0
khelper
kacpid
kblockd/0
khubd
pdflush
pdflush
kswapd0
aio/0
kseriod
scsi_eh_0
kjournald
udevd
kauditd
kjournald
kjournald
kjournald
kjournald
kjournald
klogd
portmap
rpc.idmapd
sshd
xinetd
gpm
xfs
salinfod
dbus-daemon-1
cups-config-dae
hald
kjournald
agetty
minilogd
kjournald
screen
bash
sshd
bash
```

Now some i know what their purpose is, but many i cannot even seem to track down on Google, or i just get oblique references to, such as a post from a forum in 1999 complaining about the process.

Other than tracking them down one by one is there somewhere i can go to get a better explanation?

N.B. I am not asking anyone to tell me directly what they are but pointers to where i can get the understanding myself.

Answer (score 2):

The stuff in square brackets are kernel threads. For the others, get the full name (try adding `www` to the command line) and hit Google, or look at `/proc/<pid>/exe` and use your package manager to figure out which package the executable comes from.

Comment: +1, not so much about goole; but getting the executable and from there the package is the best approach by far.

Comment: @Javier How can this be done in particular with apt-get package manager in Ubuntu? Thanks

Comment: @xralf `dpkg -S <filename>` tells you which package owns any file.

Comment: @Javier mplayer has PID 2925. dpkg -S /proc/2925/exe `dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /proc/2925/exe.`

Comment: @xralf `/proc/<id>/exe` is a symlink, not the real file name.  try `dpkg -S $(readlink -f /proc/2925/exe)`

Comment: @Javier for mplayer, the result is (mplayer: /usr/bin/mplayer), but for gdomap process (1028), it returns (dpkg-query: error: --search needs at least one file name pattern argument

Use --help for help about querying packages.)

Answer (score 1):

Some processes might have an associated manpage (the d at the end of most processes stand for daemon, you can also try the name without the d)

```
man processname
```